# Assign ID to Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdown list for a model property called `SomProperty`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SomeProperty,(SelectList)ViewBag.items)
```

where in the controller, `ViewBag.items` is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

How do I assign an ID to the dropdown list?

Comment: Whats wrong with the `id` that's already been added (i.e. `id = "SomeProperty"`)?, but if you want to override it - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty,(SelectList)ViewBag.items), new { id = "xxxx" })`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your usage is already correct. The ID will be `SomeProperty`. It will also contain the value of the item which end user selects.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SomeProperty, (SelectList)ViewBag.items, "-- Select --")
```

Still if you want to **change the default ID name** then you can do so as shown below (also describe by Stephen in comment)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SomeProperty, (SelectList)ViewBag.items, "-- Select --", new { id = "NewID"  })
```

**Bonus:** Optionally you can also specify css class for your drop down as:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SomeProperty, (SelectList)ViewBag.items, "-- Select --", new {@class = "form-control"})
```